# Element not interactable (pero visible y path correcto) - Selenium

Tags: python, script, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy escribiendo un pequeño script en Python para que entre en una web y poder navegar por ella. El problema está en que el elemento en el que quiero hacer clic parece ser no interactuable, provocando un error.

El path es el correcto, la página tiene tiempo de cargar y el elemento es visible por lo que no se que puede estár pasando.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver_service = Service(executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")

link = "https://mi_link.com"
username = "user"
password = "pass"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,service=driver_service)

driver.get(link)
 
time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys(password)

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[type="submit"]').click()

time.sleep(15)

driver.get(link)

time.sleep(10)

rel_path_1 = "//span[contains(text(),'SBO')]"

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, rel_path_1)
element.click()
```

Comment: Incluso he intentado seleccionarlo colocando el ratón encima y haciendo clic con el siguiente código 
`actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()` 
pero ahora me provoca otro error: Move target out of bounds

Comment: Además de ser visible, a veces es necesario que el elemento obtenga el foco para que sea interactivo.

Comment: @chemacortes no soy muy experto por lo que no entiendo a lo que te refieres, como podría hacer para que el elemento obtenga el foco?

Comment: Usa el método [switchto](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to). Pero si te da el error de _out of bounds_ es posible que el elemento se oculte sacándolo del _viewport_, sin depender de su atributo de visibilidad. Habría que analizar mejor el código.

Comment: @ChemaCortes El problema era que no había seleccionado el iframe. Al realizar un `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"mi_path")))`  pude encontrar la variable.